# "Non-stick" action on ceramic-coated pans

Tags: everyday-chemistry, ceramics

I understand how PTFE, or Teflon as it is commonly called, prevents anything from sticking to pans; apparently, anything coming into contact with the PTFE coating has ignorably tiny van der Waals forces with it.

However, there are also ceramic coated pans, with similar properties.

How do ceramic coated pans prevent anything from sticking onto the pan?